# Wrong image displayed for maintenance screen.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, maintenance, images

I got a screen before saying "This Stack Exchange site is currently offline for maintenance", and the image that appeared there seems to be related instead to the [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) site:

[alt text http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/offline-keyboard-layout.png](http://sstatic.net/skins/sketchy/img/offline-keyboard-layout.png)

And there is an image below that which links to [Penny Arcade](http://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2007/6/8/).

There should either be different images displayed which are specific to DIY, or just a generic message screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the generic page for all sites. It's not meant to be about gaming, but about arbitrary, extremely complex control schemes of any type.